# Using a waffle sample on Django

Tags: python, django

When using a waffle sample with Django does waffle record the users that it used the alternative code with. In that if I were to run a script that sends an email with alternative texts, would waffle remember the users I sent the normal message to and the special message to so that the same people would get the special message each time?

Comment: What is a waffle sample?

Comment: This is waffle: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-waffle